# Core Data fetch condition by content of array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working with Core Data and I found myself against a wall

One of my entities has an array of strings as a property, and I need to fetch filtering by the content of this array

I'd love to have something like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "arrayProperty CONTAINS %@", elementString)
```

Is there anything that works like that?

Comment: Is the contains predicate not working?

Comment: Nop, Its returning empty array when it shouldn't

Comment: Could you paste the code that you're using for the predicated fetch request and a print of the array that contains the string? Also the elementString that you are searching for.

Comment: Its actually throwing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I fetch with that predicate included. I'add the code to the question

Comment: Is arrayProperty a transformable attribute?  If so, I don't think you can use it in a predicate for a fetch.  You can fetch without the predicate and then filter the results using filteredArrayWithPredicate or similar.

Comment: Yes, it is a transformable attribute. So it might not be possible at all... I will try your work around @pbasdf

Comment: Alternately keep your array of strings as another core data entity with a relationship to the above entity and then use a compound query to filter.  Something like 'ANY strings.content CONTAINS %@', I can't recall the exact details of how to do this but its possible.

Comment: Just found it, like this example of a query to find all Companies with '(ANY employees.name contains[cd] $value) or (ANY employees.details.string contains[cd] $value)'